# How do i delete a file from a git repo?

Tags: git

can not seem to remove a file from git.

i have poor vision, can anyone spot what i am doing wrong?

edit: it's a type. i am deleting the wrong file :(

thanks

```
D:\ray\dev\ml\titanic>git rm .ipynb_checkpoints/tryunitesting.ipynb
fatal: pathspec '.ipynb_checkpoints/tryunitesting.ipynb' did not match any files


D:\ray\dev\ml\titanic>git rm .ipynb_checkpoints\tryunitesting.ipynb
fatal: pathspec '.ipynb_checkpoints\tryunitesting.ipynb' did not match any files


D:\ray\dev\ml\titanic>ls .ipynb_checkpoints
tryunitesting-checkpoint.ipynb

D:\ray\dev\ml\titanic>
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to remove `.ipynb_checkpoints\tryunitesting.ipynb` but the file is called `.ipynb_checkpoints\tryunitesting-checkpoint.ipynb`.

Comment: Voting to close as typo. Re your eyesight, I'd suggest you invest in a larger monitor and up the font size. Not meaning to be insulting since I had to do a similar thing :-)

Comment: oh wow,l it's the wrong file :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git rm file1.txt
git commit -m "remove file1.txt"
```

But if you want to remove the file only from the Git repository and not remove it from the filesystem, use:

```
git rm --cached file1.txt
git commit -m "remove file1.txt"
```

And to push changes to remote repo

```
git push origin branch_name
```

It seems your issue `typo`. To avoid simple mistake like this, you can use some shell plugins. Please check [this great plugin](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh).

Comment: the --cached worked fine once i fixed the typo - thanks